# Is it possible to use a function to push the document.getElementByID().innerHTML to an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, object, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am back with another question for the community. I know there are a lot of questions and answers on the subject of document.getElementByID(), but I cannot find anything that points me to the path I am looking for, and it may just not exist.

In my text based javascript game, I have a LOT of span's and am looking to shorten the length of code, as for every instance of declaring and changing the variable inside an object, to push it to the HTML page, I am having to spam the use of document.getElementByID().

For instance, in my HTML file I have:

```
<div id="attributes">
                <div id="main_attributes">
                    <p>
                        Name: <span id="Player.Name">0</span>&emsp;&emsp; Gender: <span id="Player.Gender">0</span><br />
                        Class: <span id="Player.ClassType">0</span><br /><br />
                        Health: <span id="Player.Health">0</span><br />
                        Mana: <span id="Player.Mana">0</span><br />
                        Strength: <span id="Player.Strength">0</span><br/>
                        Defense: <span id="Player.Defense">0</span><br />
                        Endurance: <span id="Player.Endurance">0</span><br />
                        Intelligence: <span id="Player.Intelligence">0</span><br />
                        Current Location: <span id="currentarea">0</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

With which I have made an object "Player" from a Hero prototype:

```
function Hero(Gender, Sexiness, Name, classType, Health, Mana, Strength, Defense, Endurance, Intelligence, Friend, Gold, BattleHealth, BattleMana, BattleStamina,  Experience, Level, Karma,) {
    this.Gender = Gender;
    this.Sexiness = Sexiness;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.ClassType = classType;
    this.Health = Health;
    this.Mana = Mana;
    this.Strength = Strength;
    this.Defense = Defense;
    this.Endurance = Endurance;
    this.Intelligence = Intelligence;
    this.Friend = Friend;
    this.Gold = Gold;
    this.BattleHealth = BattleHealth;
    this.BattleMana = BattleMana;
    this.BattleStamina = BattleStamina;
    this.Experience = Experience;
    this.Level = Level;
    this.Karma = Karma;
}
let Player = new Hero("Spirit", 0, "Spirit", "Undetermined One", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "None", 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

Defined some constants:

```
const Male = {
    Type: "Male",
    Health: 100,
    Mana: 20,
    Strength: 20,
    Defense: 5,
    Endurance: 15,
    Intelligence: 5,
    Sexiness: 1,
    Friend: "Duncan",
}
const Female = {
    Type: "Female",
    Health: 80,
    Mana: 60,
    Strength: 16,
    Defense: 4,
    Endurance: 12,
    Intelligence: 10,
    Sexiness: 2,
    Friend: "Morgana",
}
```

And a gender assign function:

```
function genderAssign() {
    switch (Player.Gender) {
        case "Male":
            Player.Gender = Male.Type;
            Player.Health = Male.Health;
            Player.Mana = Male.Mana;
            Player.Strength = Male.Strength;
            Player.Defense = Male.Defense;
            Player.Endurance = Male.Endurance;
            Player.Intelligence = Male.Intelligence;
            Player.Sexiness = Male.Sexiness;
            Player.Friend = Male.Friend;
            Armor.UpperClothesName = "Chest";
            Armor.LowerClothesName = "Fig Leaves";
            Armor.HelmetName = "Head";
            Armor.BodyName = "Body";
            Armor.ArmName = "Arms";
            Armor.WaistName = "None";
            Armor.LegName = "Legs";
            Armor.BootsName = "Feet";
            Weapons.RightHand = "Right Hand";
            Weapons.LeftHand = "Left Hand";
            Armor.LegCoveringsName = "Hair";
            break;
        case "Female":
            Player.Gender = Female.Type;
            Player.Health = Female.Health;
            Player.Mana = Female.Mana;
            Player.Strength = Female.Strength;
            Player.Defense = Female.Defense;
            Player.Endurance = Female.Endurance;
            Player.Intelligence = Female.Intelligence;
            Player.Sexiness = Female.Sexiness;
            Armor.UpperClothesName = "Nip Coverings";
            Armor.LowerClothesName = "Fig Leaves";
            Armor.HelmetName = "Head";
            Armor.BodyName = "Body";
            Armor.ArmName = "Arms";
            Armor.WaistName = "None";
            Armor.LegName = "Legs";
            Armor.BootsName = "Feet";
            Weapons.RightHand = "Right Hand";
            Weapons.LeftHand = "Left Hand";
            Armor.LegCoveringsName = "Smooth Legs";
            Player.Friend = Female.Friend;
            break;
        default:
    }
    return;
}
```

I don't want to have to do something as follows:

```
            Player.Gender = Male.Type;
            document.getElementByID("Male.Type").innerHTML = Male.Type
            Player.Health = Male.Health;
            document.getElementByID("Male.Health").innerHTML = Male.Health
            Player.Mana = Male.Mana;
            document.getElementByID("Male.Mana").innerHTML = Male.Mana
```

And so on...
Is there a way to do something like:

```
function printPlayer() {

    Player.Gender = $('#Player.Gender');
    Player.Sexiness = $('#Player.Sexiness');
    Player.Health = $('#Player.Health');
    Player.Mana = $('#Player.Mana');
    Player.Strength = $('#Player.Strength');
    Player.Defense = $('#Player.Defense');
    Player.Endurance = $('#Player.Endurance');
    Player.Intelligence = $('#Player.Intelligence');
    Player.Friend = $('#Player.Friend');
    Player.Gold = $('#Player.Gold');
    Player.Experience = $('#Player.Experience');
    Player.Level = $('#Player.Level');
    Player.ClassType = $('#Player.ClassType');
}
```

OR

```
function printPlayer() {

    document.getElementById("Player.Sexiness").innerHTML = Player.Sexiness;
    document.getElementById("Player.Health").innerHTML = Player.Health;
    document.getElementById("Player.Mana").innerHTML = Player.Mana;
    document.getElementById("Player.Strength").innerHTML = Player.Strength;
    document.getElementById("Player.Defense").innerHTML = Player.Defense;
    document.getElementById("Player.Endurance").innerHTML = Player.Endurance;
    document.getElementById("Player.Intelligence").innerHTML = Player.Intelligence;
    document.getElementById("Player.Friend").innerHTML = Player.Friend;
    document.getElementById("Player.Gold").innerHTML = Player.Gold;
    document.getElementById("Player.Experience").innerHTML = Player.Experience;
    document.getElementById("Player.Level").innerHTML = Player.Level;
    document.getElementById("Player.ClassType").innerHTML = Player.ClassType;
}
```

And call it from within, say the genderAssign() function?

Sorry if this is a bit lengthy, but I'd rather give you a broader scope of what I am doing rather than leave it to guessing. I have tried the above functions, and neither seem to work. The error is:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is nullUpdatePlayerCharacter.js:22:14

printPlayer file:///C:/Users/Melseph/Desktop/Game Design/PhoenixDestitute/scripts/UpdatePlayerCharacter.js:22

genderAssign file:///C:/Users/Melseph/Desktop/Game Design/PhoenixDestitute/scripts/CharacterStats.js:78

<anonymous> file:///C:/Users/Melseph/Desktop/Game Design/PhoenixDestitute/scripts/PhoenixDestitute.js:45
jQuery 2
```

Which I am assuming is because I don't have the values inside the printPlayer() function, but there in is where I am stuck and cannot find anymore direction. Is it just impossible to do it the way I am trying?

--Edit--

I always seem to leave this part out, which is why I think everyone tends to want to point towards a button, which is my mistake, sorry...

I have a form for the user to answer questions and a window that shows updates the player makes, and I had it all working with added document.getElementByID()... which (of course) killed it when I took those out. I can see through console.log(Player) that all the items are being updated in the Player object, but I cannot find an easier method of pushing the innerHTML to the HTML file.

Here is what my code is for the console id and a screenshot:

```
<div class="console">
<div id="console_wrapper">
    <div id="console">
        <p>Would you like to begin your adventure? Type <u><b>yes</b></u> or <u><b>no</b></u>.</p>
        <!--
        PLACEHOLDER: THIS IS WHERE YOUR CHOICES ARE INPUT
        -->
        <div id="placeholder"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="command_line" placeholder="User Input Here" autofocus="autofocus" />
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#console").fadeIn(3000); //Console fades in.
$(document).keypress(function(key) { //When a key is press:
    if (key.which === 13 && $('#command_line').is(':focus')) { //If enter key is pressed and the focus is on the command line:
        var input = $('#command_line').val().toLowerCase(); //Express what is in the command line in lower case.
        $('#command_line').val(""); //Erase the value of what is shown in the command box.
        $("#console").animate({ scrollTop: "999999999px" }, 'slow'); //Scroll the console to the bottom.
     }
}
```

[image]

Not sure if this changes the answer to my question any, or if the use of a button is the only method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet should give you some ideas for handling properties of your Player object, including showing them on the page.
(See the in-code comments for explanations of particular features of the script.)

```js
//Identifies button for demo
const myButton = document.getElementById("my-button");

// Calls `printInfoToPage` method when button is clicked
myButton.addEventListener("click", printInfoToPage);

// Defines Player object
const Player = {
  Sexiness: 5,
  Health: 5,
  Mana: 3,
  Strength: 4,
  Defense: 3,
  BowlingScore: 5
};

// (Arrow function) prepends "Player." to its string argument 
const mapPropNameToElementId = (propName) => "Player." + propName;

// Takes two strings, updates textContent of matching element if possible
function setElementTextById(id, text){
  element = document.getElementById(id);
  if(element){ // Makes sure element exists before proceeding
    element.textContent = text; // `.innerHTML` would also work
  }
};

function printInfoToPage(){

  // Static `.keys` method on `Object` gets an object's property names
  const playerPropNames = Object.keys(Player);

  // `for...of` loops through array
  for(let prop of playerPropNames){

    // Gets IDs
    const elementId = mapPropNameToElementId(prop);
    
    // Gets value
    const storedValue = Player[prop];

    // Updates element on page
    setElementTextById(elementId, storedValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Sexiness: </span><span id="Player.Sexiness"></span> <br/>
<span>Health: </span><span id="Player.Health"></span> <br/>
<span>Mana: </span><span id="Player.Mana"></span> <br/>
<span>Strength: </span><span id="Player.Strength"></span> <br/>
<span>Defense: </span><span id="Player.Defense"></span> <br/>
<br/>
<button id="my-button">Show Player Info</button>
```

**Edit**
BTW, the code can be (shorter and/or) more reusable. I often use more verbose code for clarity, but writing the same imperative code repeatedly makes it not just verbose but more error-prone and harder to maintain.

If you want to handle various groups of properties (ie various objects, eg armor and weapon), the `printInfoToPage` function can be revised to take an object and its identifying string as arguments, something like:

```js
const
  category1 = { prop1: 111, prop2: 222 },
  category2 = { prop3: 333, prop4: 444 },
  printInfoToPage = (prefix, group) => {
    for(let prop in group){// `for...in` is for objects
      setElementValueById(prefix + prop, group[prop]);
    }
  },
  setElementValueById = (id, val) => {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    // `input` elements have a `value` property
    if(el?.tagName == "INPUT"){ el.value = val; }
  };

printInfoToPage("category1.", category1);
printInfoToPage("category2.", category2);
```

```html
<label> prop1: <input id="category1.prop1" /></label><br />
<label> prop2: <input id="category1.prop2" /></label><br />
<br />
<label> prop3: <input id="category2.prop3" /></label><br />
<label> prop4: <input id="category2.prop4" /></label>
```

Comment: That answer does work, but not 100% what I was looking for... which is my fault for not putting all the information needed upfront. I do need the event listener, but I need it on the key.which === 13 (basically on.mouseUp or something like that) so it passes through the if statement on the main code page. I think that would completely answer my question. I am also looking on how to make this button an mouseUp property instead.

Comment: You probably want `keyup` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) ... It seems like `event.key == "Enter"` is the more modern test to use, but I expect you could get away with `"event.which == 13"` just fine. Try it and see!

Comment: Lol! Yes, I meant keyup... maybe I need to go back to bed.

Comment: That absolutely worked and was the answer to my question. Thank you very much!